# plotting the sum of an array array[0:i] vs i

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

This is a simple question, but I seem to be stuck:

Let's say there is an array of 1000 values, i.e.

```
import numpy
arr = np.arange(1000)
```

I would like to plot these values along the x-axis with the sum of these values against the y-axis. For example, 0:0, 1:1, 2:3, 3:6, 4:10, 5:15, 6:21, etc. Furthermore, I would like to do this as efficiently as possible using `np.sum()`.

Using matplotlib, the xaxis is `arr`. How would you code the y-axis? 
Perhaps

```
def summation(i):
    return np.sum(arr[0:i])
```

and then use this function to create an array? That doesn't quite work.

Comment: Could you please clarify the meaning of the numbers "1:1, 2:3, 3:5, 4:9, 5:14, 6:20, etc"?  Also, see comments in @farenorth's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `cumsum`. For example:

```
y = np.cumsum(arr)
```

To plot the data, you could simply do,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(arr, y)
```

Good luck!

Comment: How does this deal with the ranges that were requested, ie, "[f]or example, 1:1, 2:3, 3:5, 4:9, 5:14, 6:20, etc"?

Comment: I'm not sure those values are consistent with the definition of `arr`, and the definition of `summation`. Not only should the first pair be `0:0`, but I believe the 3rd+ should be one higher than they are. Unless I'm missing something? If @ShanZhengYang makes his question consistent, I'll make my answer specific.